# Paperclip / Windows7 / Rails 3.1 "Identify" issue... no posted solutions working. How do i fix this or get more information?

Tags: paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3.1, windows-7-x64

I'm having the common " is not recognized by the 'identify' command." error using paperclip and rails 3.1 on my windows dev machine.  This is a win7/64 system with `ImageMagick-6.7.3-0-Q16-windows-x64-dll.exe` installed at c:\ImageMagick.

I've tried all of the solutions listed under at https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpaperclip%5D+identify and it keeps giving me the same answers.

`Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "C:/ImageM~1"` is in my config/enviroments/development.rb

and

`Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:command_path] = "C:/ImageM~1"` is the contents of my config/initializers/paperclip.rb

I can use identify at the command prompt...and that is working fine. It seems like no matter what i do, it keeps throwing the same error.

link.rb
`has_attached_file :artwork,
        :styles => {
          :thumb=> "100x100#",
          :small  => "150x150#" }`

_form.html.erb
`<%= f.file_field :artwork %>`

please help. i am out of options. anything else i should try or anywhere to get more information as to where this is failing?

**UPDATE**
i've removed the ':style => .....' attributes in the model and it now works. i guess it's just straight imagemagick messing up. i don't get it. i can type 'identify' in the console, it works fine, then i run 'rails s' in the same console. there were references to a quotes related issue, but according to the paperclip docs on github, that was sorted when Cocaine was implemented.

Comment: I've now tried this on two different win7 PCs. One is 32, the other is 64 and neither is working. same exact error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing RMagick and Imagemagick following these articles fixed it!

This is the article that actually solved the problem:
http://rails.webintellix.com/2010/01/04/how-to-install-rmagick-imagemagick-on-windows/
Basically, installing the RMagick win32 binary sorted the 'identify' issue...

This one got close and has some good info, but didn't actually fix it for me.
http://www.waydotnet.com/blog/2010/02/rmagick-on-ruby-1-9-1-i386-mingw32-work-d/